# How to get top 4 result from a list using linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list, and the list values are

```
Result26_05_2014_15_38_50, 
Result27_05_2014_09_46_26, 
Result27_05_2014_11_18_46,
Result27_05_2014_13_43_40, 
Result27_05_2014_13_53_03, 
Result27_05_2014_14_19_15
```

my first requirement is to get the max from this

```
  var t = (from li in list select li).Max();
```

it showed me `Result27_05_2014_14_19_15`.

my second requirement is to get top 4 ie

```
Result27_05_2014_11_18_46,
Result27_05_2014_13_43_40, 
Result27_05_2014_13_53_03,
Result27_05_2014_14_19_15
```

how to do this

Comment: What does this do `from li in list select li` ? and why?

Comment: How do you want to order your values? Are they strings? It looks like they contain dates, so do you want to order by date?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It's LINQ so it automatically makes your code better :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An OrderBy will do it.

```
 var t = (from li in list
         orderby li descending
         select li).Take(4);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can order by  and then get first n element with `Take(n)` method.

```
var result = (from li in list orderby li descending select li).Take(4);
```

*or*

```
var result = list.OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order your list and apply the Take method to get the n elements of the list.

Sorry I'm away from keyboard right now and I can't give you the exact code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = list.OrderByDescending(l=> l).Take(4);
```